# EditText should not be empty in xml File

Tags: java, android

is there a attribut for the xml file where I can say, that it is not allowed that the EditText is empty?

Thanks

Comment: I think no.....

Comment: There is a `maxLength` property for `EditText`, but I don't think there is an XML way to impose a minimum length.  But it is easy enough to implement some simple validation programatically (q.v. the duplicate link).